# Angular 8 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an application which is using Angular 8 as a framework. I need to add one third party tool (mergely) which is using jQuery as its dependency.

Mergely can work with Angular 8, but adding jQuery to application bundle is required. I am worried whether adding jQuery will affect application performance in a negative way.

Is there any evidence that adding jQuery to application affected Angular performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think adding jQuery will impact angular's performance. Of course, you'll have an increased bundle size (jQuery,minified and compressed is 30 kB I think) and extra time for the browser to parse the jQuery lib.

The main problem with using jquery with angular is that jQuery can modify the dom outside of angular's zone, meaning that angular does not know about your changes.  This can lead to unwanted side effect

Comment: yes, I am aware of risk that DOM might be modified out of Angular's scope. Also bundle size rise is acceptable for me. This makes just first request slower. I was just worried that overall DOM rendering performance and responding to user events will be slower.